# C# UWP Getting Error using System.Net.Http HttpClient

Tags: c#, uwp, httpclient

I've trouble with  my UWP-App connecting my server
I'm connected via VPN to my office
I can reach the server from any Browser

Here my code:

```
string host = "https://server.local:8001/xxx";
string url = "/ANGP300/Angebot";

HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler;
HttpClient httpClient;

httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

try
{
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage
   {
       Method = HttpMethod.Get,
       RequestUri = new Uri(host + url),
       Headers = {
          { "User-Agent", "vscode-restclient" },
          { "Accept-Language", "de-DE;q=0.9" }
       }
   };

   using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request)) //Getting error here
   {
       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       JToken parsedJson = JToken.Parse(body);
   }
}

catch (Exception)
{

}
```

I'm getting an error: "A connection with the server could not be established"

**I've already tried this:** checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=MY_PACKAGENAME
but without any success

**Trying this:** CheckNetIsolation.exe debug -n=MY_PACKAGENAME shows following:

```
Detaillierter Datenverkehrsbericht
----------------------------------------------------------------------
InternetClient                Not Used and Insecure
------------------------------------------------------------------
InternetClientServer          Not Used and Insecure
------------------------------------------------------------------
PrivateNetworkClientServer    Not Used and Insecure
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why no connection is showing up? Has anyone a clue?

**Manifest:**

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <Capability Name="internetClientServer"/>
  <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer"/>
  <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication"/>
</Capabilities>
```

**Alternative:** I've tried the HttpClient from Windows.Web.Http Namespace; the error is still there

**BTW:** Same code in a console apps works perfectly.

Do you have any ideas what I can do? I suppose it has to do with the active VPN-connection?! It's configured via systemsconfiguration and has LT2P/IPSec

Thanks a lot

***Remarks:***
I've tried to figure out why I still have those issues. I think I nailed it down to the VPN-Connection of my office. I couldn't even connect to public webservices when the VPN-Connection was active.

When I use  Pwoershell Get-NetConnectionsProfile I get those results:

```
Name             : company.local
InterfaceAlias   : company.VPN
InterfaceIndex   : 108
NetworkCategory  : DomainAuthenticated
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic
```

When I use another VPN-Connection I got those results:

```
Name             : anothercompany.local
InterfaceAlias   : anothercompany.VPN
InterfaceIndex   : 108
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic
```

I have no problems to connect to public webservices.

I guess it has to to with the Networkcategory. Any Ideas how to tell the httpclient to accept/use DomainAuthenticated-VPN?

Any help would be appreciated. Again this is only when using UWP... In a .netcore app I have no problems at all... but I want to create an UWP-App

**@Roy Li: Your help is deeply appreciated!!!**

The errocode in my UWP-App:
HResult = -2147012867

Message = "An error occurred while sending the request."

Innerexception = "Der Text zu diesem Fehlercode wurde nicht gefunden.\r\n\r\nDie Serververbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden.\r\n"

***Remarks II:*** With Fiddler active capturing traffic, I don't get any error message from my UWP-App and I receive values as expected. I seems that Fiddler bypass the VPN somehow?!

Below the code of my Consoleapp which works fine with or without Fiddler... I use the same coe for my UWP-App

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Task.Run(async () => { await GetTaskAsync(); }).Wait();
        }

        public static async Task GetTaskAsync()
        {

            string host = "https://server.local:8001/apiworkshop-amspro/WebModules/ams.erp ServerHost";
            string url = "/ANGP300/Angebot";

            HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri(host+url),
                Headers = {
                                        { "User-Agent", "vscode-restclient" },
                                        { "Accept-Language", "de-DE;q=0.9" }
                                    }
            };

            using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(body, new ExpandoObjectConverter());

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> jsonItem in jsonObject)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(jsonItem.Key + ": " + jsonItem.Value);
                    if(jsonItem.Key == "value" && jsonItem.Value is IEnumerable<object> valueList)
                    {
                        foreach (dynamic valueItem in valueList)
                        {
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> valueAttr in valueItem)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(valueAttr.Key + ": " + valueAttr.Value + "(" + (valueAttr.Value?.GetType()?.ToString() ?? "No Type") + ")");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable the Enterprise Authentication capability in the package manifest?

Comment: Yep. I still get the error

Comment: I noticed that you are trying to accessing a localhost address. Could you please try to [Enabling loopback for a UWP application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback#enabling-loopback-for-a-uwp-application) first?

Comment: I've already checked this... did not help, or did I something wrong?

Comment: What about the `privateNetworkClientServer` capability? Have you enabled this in your manifest file?

Comment: Another thing is that we'd suggest use Network APIs from [Windows.Web.Http Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http?view=winrt-19041) because sometimes APIs from the `System.Net.Http Namespace` does work in UWP apps.

Comment: PrivateNetworkClientServer capability checked. HttpClient from Windows.Web.Http Namespace checked. => Error remains the same

Comment: @thezapper could you please use fiddler to catch the networking trace when you trying to connect to the server?

Comment: It's the first time I use Fiddler... where can I find the network trace? But with the "Capture Traffic" On I can get my data even when VPN is active. When I stop capturing traffic, I'll get my error back ;(

Comment: @thezapper, could you please check the HTTP request result sent both in your app and console app? You could share the error code and error message about the HTTP request that shown in the Fiddler. Or could you please share an example about how you use the System.Net.Http namespace in a simple demo. You could share it with us on Github or OneDrive.

Comment: @thezapper The reason for that failure is the network isolation of UWP apps.  UWP apps are running in the sandbox so UWP apps have limitations when accessing local networks. Generally, the loopback setting should help in this scenario but the VPN makes it a little different. I'm not sure how Fiddler is implemented, but it seems Fiddler could bypass the isolation and VPN.